# How to safely save user inputed code to the database

Tags: php, cakephp, sanitize, saving-data

I have section on my site where users can submit code. I want to safely store to the database.

I am using php. I tried using html purifier to save data to the database, but it removes all the code.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: So, just store it like any other text

Comment: Why do you want to santize the data?  Just make sure the code isn't executed.

Comment: Just escape it using `mysql_real_escape_string()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you save to the database using cakephp's save method, you are automatically protected from SQL injection.

Useful Link:

> http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2009/08/06/save-now-sanitize-later/